# Error $content_for_layout trying to customize flash messages

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I'm trying to customize the flash messages for my application and for that I've created 3 files inside /app/Views/Elements and called them flash_error.ctp, flash_information.ctp and flash_success.ctp. The difference between them is the CSS class applied. The content is the same and is as follow:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
  <strong>Warning!</strong> <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
</div>
```

But when I try to show any flash message using:

```
$this->Session->flash();
```

for example I get this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: content_for_layout [APP/View/Elements/flash_success.ctp, line 3]

Why? Can any help me here? I'm stucked!!! :-(

Comment: where you creating `$content_for_layout`?

Comment: no where, should I define in some place? I just take the idea from this site http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/custom_cakephp_flash_messages_updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

To use your flash message, you need to call it in the setFlash method. For example, if you call it from a a successfully saved customer it would look like this:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The customer has been saved'), 'yourCustomFlashMessage');
```

Then, you make sure that you have `views/elements/your_custom_flash_message.ctp`

Comment: Ok and how I know from template if the var is setup or not? Sometimes I get user login messages in other templates just because they was setup before :-(

Comment: Just make sure you add the template you want to use in the setFlash method wherever you want to use it. See the update to my post above.